# How do I set up an automatic command that will flood a world map (170x170) by 1 level every minute?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to set up a world with a border that is 170x170 blocks, and every minute water will rise by one block across the entire map. This will keep happening until the map is full of water. I just want to replace the air blocks and leave everything else alone.

I am very new to command blocks and I don't really know how to use their commands properly.

An example of what I am trying to do is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkPXyXlQ7Hc), but I want to set it up so that it is automatic.

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJYBloWiYnQ) but the commands are outdated and don't work in 1.14.14 Java edition.

Answer (score 5):

Ok so here's the command block part of it that you need:

[image: Simple Rising Flood Testing]

Ok, so I just made this real quick. The numbers here reference the command to the command block closest to that respective number.

1. `/summon armor_stand X Y Z {Tags:["Flood"],Invisisble:1b,NoGravity:1b,Marker:1b}`
2. `/execute as @e[tag=Flood] at @s run fill ~-X_DIST ~ ~-Z_DIST ~X_DIST ~ ~Z_DIST water replace air`
3. `/execute as @e[tag=Flood] at @e[tag=Flood] run tp @e[tag=Flood] ~ ~1 ~`

Notes:

- Command block 1 ONLY needs to be run once. Replace the XYZ with the middle of the region
- Replace the X_DIST and Z_DIST with the however many blocks the armor stand is away from the border
- Command block 2's arrow NEEDS to point to command block 3, and both must be activated. You could probably just make command block 3 and always active chain command block which is connected to command block 2.
- Command block 1 actually SPAWNS the armor stand. In the command, I have it invisible  and untouchable, so it won't affect anything. You can make it visible by changing the tag "invisible:1b" to "invisible:0b". You can make the armor stand interactable (able to break it by hand, etc) by changing the tag "Marker:1b" to "Marker:0b". If you want to reference the armor stand, you can reference it using the target modifier "Tag=Flood". So if you want to kill it for instance, you would use the command `/kill @e[tag=Flood]`
- In order to make the flood move upwards, attach some sort of timer (like a hopper clock for instance) to command block 2

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Is there a way of setting up a timer with command blocks at all by using an in game timer or something like that, or would I have to set up a hopper clock?