# How do I cover my entire world in water?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to cover my entire world in water and make it look like it’s flooded and the water has covered mountains and villages.
Can someone give me a command to use?

Comment: Maybe this will work. Link: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/355984/how-do-i-set-up-an-automatic-command-that-will-flood-a-world-map-170x170-by-1/355995

Comment: @AaronHenderson NBT essentially doesn't exist in MCBE, so the first command won't work.

Answer (score 5):

You can brute force this with the `clone` and `fill` commands, along with a few command blocks.

---

##### ⚡️ Get Command Blocks

You can't craft command blocks, nor can you find them in the creative menu. Instead you'll need to use the `give` command to give yourself one:

```
give @s command_block
```

##### The Concept

In order for this to work, you need to create a self replicating system. It's slow, but, it'll work. This answer will create a *basic* system that uses a stack of command blocks to wrap itself with stacks of command blocks. So we'll start with a single column, and the world will slowly fill with more and more columns by creating `3x3` grids:

[image: Screenshot of gold and emerald blocks demonstrating the aforementioned grid.]

In the screenshot above, the emerald block represents the initial column, and the gold blocks represent the columns it creates. Since each of the newly created columns are ***exact*** copies of the original column, this creates a recursive system that self replicates forever.

For the purposes of this post, I will ***NOT*** be demonstrating how to stop the system, but it *can* be stopped with the `scoreboard` and `testfor` commands and some changes to the layout, taking into account the rules surrounding water.

##### ⌨️ Placement and Commands

For this to work, you'll need to create a 10 block high column of command blocks that feed into each other. I ***highly*** recommend building this in the sky as I did so that structures are unimpacted, but you *can* place it anywhere. The commands are as follows, assuming that the lowest command block is line 1 and the highest is line 10, respectively:

```
clone ~ ~ ~ ~ ~10 ~ ~1 ~ ~
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~9 ~ ~-1 ~-1 ~
clone ~ ~-2 ~ ~ ~8 ~ ~ ~-2 ~1
clone ~ ~-3 ~ ~ ~7 ~ ~ ~-3 ~-1
clone ~ ~-4 ~ ~ ~6 ~ ~1 ~-4 ~1
clone ~ ~-5 ~ ~ ~5 ~ ~-1 ~-5 ~1
clone ~ ~-6 ~ ~ ~4 ~ ~1 ~-6 ~-1
clone ~ ~-7 ~ ~ ~3 ~ ~-1 ~-7 ~-1
fill ~ ~-125 ~ ~ ~ ~ water 0 replace air
fill ~ ~-10 ~ ~ ~ ~ water
```

The way this works, is that each `clone` block is responsible for cloning the entire column to one of the surrounding coordinates. Then, the last two blocks are responsible for replacing air with water and removing the command blocks.

##### Configurations

The configurations are relatively straightforward. The lowest command block (block 1) is the only one with a repeating configuration:

```
Repeat
Unconditional
Always Active
100 Tick Delay
```

***Note**: Do **NOT** set the configuration for the lowest command block until all others have been set. If you trigger the system before you're done with all the other command blocks, they will begin overwriting each other, preventing you from finishing the system and forcing you to create a new world.*

Command blocks 2 through 8, ***plus*** command block 10, should be given a chain configuration with the no delay:

```
Chain
Conditional
Always Active
0 Tick Delay
```

Finally, the 9<sup>th</sup> command block should be given a delay of ***less than or equal to*** the delay in ticks used for the lowest block, to ensure the newly created columns don't overwrite it:

```
Chain
Conditional
Always Active
50 Tick Delay
```

##### The Result

A world full of water!

[image: Screenshot of some tree tops under water.]

##### Be Careful

Since this is a recursive system, it may take a few attempts to get it right, so work with it in a new world until you understand what it's doing, and are confident that you won't botch the setup:

[image: Screenshot giving an example of what can go wrong with the setup]

[image: Another screenshot giving an example of what can go wrong with the setup]

Comment: I realize I can't award the bounty until a day later lol, whatever

Comment: @c1uq92 thanks!  don’t forget that you can upvote the answer too!